# JavaFX Entered Mouse Event Delay/Lag

Tags: javafx

I've created a grid of Rectangle objects and added them to a Pane. Each rectangle has a mouse event listener attached to it which get triggered by the MouseEvent.Entered trigger. The handler simply changes the colour of the rectangle when the user moves the mouse over the rectangle. The issue is that the trigger seems to have a considerable delay before it gets executed. Any ideas how to speed this up so its realtime with the mouse?

I've uploaded a recording here: https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cFQI0lqdHe

```
public class WarehouseMap extends Pane {

    private int xSpaces = 200;
    private int ySpaces = 100;
    private ArrayList<Rectangle> gridReferences = new ArrayList<Rectangle> ();

    public WarehouseMap() {
        setWidth(2000);
        setHeight(1000);
        initGrid();
    }

    public void initGrid() {
        double rectWidth = getWidth() / xSpaces;
        double rectHeight = getHeight() / ySpaces;

        for(int x=0; x<xSpaces; x++) {
            for(int y=0; y<ySpaces; y++) { 
                Rectangle gr = new Rectangle(x*rectWidth, y*rectHeight, rectWidth, rectHeight);
                gr.setStroke(Color.GRAY);
                gr.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                gr.setStrokeWidth(1);
                gr.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        gr.setFill(Color.DARKGRAY);
                    }

                });

                gr.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent> () {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        gr.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    }

                });

                gridReferences.add(gr);
                this.getChildren().add(gr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Canvas` to create a more faster view:

```
public class WarehouseCanvasMap extends Pane {
    private int xSpaces = 200;
    private int ySpaces = 100;
    private int cellSize = 10;
    private int lineSize = 1;
    private Canvas canvas;

    public WarehouseCanvasMap() {
        setWidth(xSpaces * cellSize);
        setHeight(ySpaces * cellSize);
        initGrid();
    }

    public void initGrid() {
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setWidth(getWidth());
        canvas.setHeight(getHeight());
        getChildren().add(canvas);
        GraphicsContext graphic = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        graphic.setStroke(Color.GRAY);
        graphic.setFill(Color.DARKGRAY);
        graphic.setLineWidth(lineSize);

        canvas.setOnMouseMoved(event -> {
            graphic.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

            graphic.fillRect(event.getX() - event.getX() % cellSize, event.getY() - event.getY() % cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);

            for (int x = 0; x <= xSpaces; x++) {
                graphic.strokeLine(x * cellSize, 0, x * cellSize, canvas.getHeight());
            }
            for (int y = 0; y <= xSpaces; y++) {
                graphic.strokeLine(0, y * cellSize, canvas.getWidth(), y * cellSize);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This solution looks like this:
[image]

And it looks faster that original:
[image]

Comment: This is a Great Answer!

Comment: Thanks, defiantly faster. JavaFX version of Swing's paint method. Answered the question perfectly. FYI: I reassessed the requirements analysis and lowered the number of rectangles considerably, my original solution was responsive enough for my needs and can easily give me access to the Rectangle Object, It seems the more event listeners there are the worst the performance becomes. Heres what my implantation now looks like: https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cFQbeOqMc6

Comment: It looks great and fast. Good luck whis your project.